# Getting Bluetooth Headphones to control system volume

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I have gotten Ubuntu 20.04 configured to support everything on my WH-H910Ns, including LDAC output to them in PulseAudio. They sound much better than on Windows 10. ;)

However, the system volume and the volume on the headphones is distinct, unlike like on Android, iOS, and Windows 10. I was just wondering how to make them the same so that when I change the volume on the headphones, it directly changes the volume on the system and vice versa.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Did you ever get this working?